# Get member last commit date using the PyGitHub library

Tags: python, github-api

I am developing a python script which requires me to get a list of all GitHub organization members who did not perform commits for a long time for any organization repository. By that  we would like to find non active members and remove them from the organization

Any ideas on how to get member last commit date using the PyGitHub library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Search commit API](https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-commits) and filter with repo of your organization using the `org` parameter :

```
GET https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=[SEARCH REQUEST]
```

You need to use the header `Accept: application/vnd.github.cloak-preview` to use this API. The following gives all the commits made in a repository owned by a specific organization for a specific user, and sorted by most recent first :

```bash
curl -s -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.cloak-preview" \
    https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=author:fgette%20org:BboxLab%20sort:author-date-desc
```

You can then filter the date of most recent commit in that organization :

```bash
curl -s -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.cloak-preview" \
    https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=author:fgette%20org:BboxLab%20sort:author-date-desc | \
    jq -r '.items[0].commit.author.date'
```

Using [python](/questions/tagged/python) you would use the following to check if the most recent commit is inferior to a deadline (here < 12 months from now) :

```
from github import Github
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

deadline = datetime.combine(
    date.today() + relativedelta(months=-12), 
    datetime.min.time()
)

g = Github("YOUR_TOKEN", per_page = 1)

commits = g.search_commits(
    query = 'author:fgette org:BboxLab sort:author-date-desc'
)

data = commits.get_page(0)

if (len(data) > 0):
    last_commit = data[0].commit.author.date
    print(f'last commit : {last_commit}')
    if (last_commit < deadline):
        print("too old :(")
    else:
        print("ok :)")
```

Output :

> last commit : 2019-03-06 15:29:26
>
> too old :(

Comment: Thanks! your answer was very useful. Since I have around 200 organization members and most of them have hundreds of commits, I'm facing now an API rate limit issue. 
I have to iterate your code on each org member and got an error after 10 first members:  403 {"message": "API rate limit exceeded for user ID MY_ID.", "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting"}. I know that the limit is 5000 per hour for authenticated user. Can I somehow limit my query for users with zero commits only?

Comment: @DimaKreisserman use a personal access token with `g = Github("YOUR_TOKEN")` From the API doc : `For API requests using Basic Authentication or OAuth, you can make up to 5000 requests per hour.` and for your case `For unauthenticated requests, the rate limit allows for up to 60 requests per hour. `

Comment: I do use a personal token. The error is still there. I solved the issue by running the query in bulks of 10 members with 60 sec sleep between them.

Comment: @DimaKreisserman I've found out the api rate limit is [different for the search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#rate-limit). Also I've updated the code with `per_page=1` in the `qualifier` attribute. For some reason pygithub was sending 2 requests each time if you don't set this parameter

Comment: @DimaKreisserman so with the update you would be able to raise to 30 per minutes instead of 10

Comment: running with `per_page=1` qualifier return no commits

Comment: @DimaKreisserman Sorry I misunderstood how the library works in fact using `commits.get_page(0)` is the right way see the updated code. I was using `commits.total_count` which was sending a new request to get the count (so it was 2 requests)

Answer (score 0):

The repository object has an API `get_commits`. It has a parameter `author`. You can use the userid or email address of the author and get all the commits for that particular author for a particular repository.

After that you have to compare the timestamps received and find out the last commit date and time.

This is the output format returned by the API.
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/

API doc: https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html#github.Repository.Repository.get_commits

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is an option to the OP's question but I managed to use BeatifulSoup to find the last commit date and time from Github pages.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "GIT URL HERE"
response = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")
relative = soup.find_all("relative-time")
dtime = relative[0].get('datetime')
print(dtime)
```

Will get something similar to this:

```
2020-06-10T19:17:19Z
```